# Identify platform on which Spring boot application is running

Tags: spring, spring-boot, platform

I have a spring boot application. The application is targeted to be deployed to AWS, EKS, Azure and VMs. This is all done and controlled by a Jenkins file and CI/CD tools like Jenkins and Spinnker etc.

I can just edit targetDeployment type variable to any platform as needed and the deployment will happen.

Is there a way that could be built in the Spring boot application itself to identify which platform the current instance is running on ?

Comment: There is no way you can know what platform is being used from spring boot. Just create an environment variable and store the platform name value and read it from your spring boot app

Answer (score 0):

You can add an infrastructure specific profiles to the spring boot while deploying and then expose it via actuator info endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure and aws there is a metadata service available that is reachable under http://169.254.169.254/. Based on the answer you‘ll be able to know where your service is running. I‘d suggest you check the documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/instance-metadata-service
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html